# ordering by birthday sql

Tags: sql

I'm working on a table `student` and I want to select student's born in the 90s. This is how I'm trying to do this:

```
dbGetQuery(con, 
    "SELECT name, forname, bdate 
    FROM student 
    WHERE (bdate < 1990.01.01) OR (bdate > 1999.12.31) 
    ORDER BY id"
)
```

but i get this error:

> Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near ".01": syntax error.

Comment: You need to convert date using str_to_date

Comment: Use quotes `'` to enclose the dates and convert to date type if needed and remember `<` means **less than** and `>` means **greater than**

Comment: Btw, your logic tries to *exclude* students born in the 90s :-)

Answer (score 4):

The dates are not typed correctly. You don't mention which database you are using so I'll refer to the SQL standard. You should:

- Enclose the literal dates in single quotes.
- Prepend the word `DATE` to the date value.
- There's no need to extra parenthesis.

Your SQL query should look like:

```
SELECT name, forname, bdate 
FROM student 
WHERE bdate between date '1990-01-01' and date '1999-12-31'
ORDER BY id
```